# How do you upload a file to the Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Object store using C#

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0, bare-metal, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How do you access the Oracle Object store in the Oracle Bare Metal Cloud using c#. 
I am looking to run the similar code below in c# within a .NET program:

```
static IAmazonS3 client;
using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) 
{
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest 
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = keyName
};

using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))  
{
    string dest = 
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
keyName);
    if (!File.Exists(dest))
    {
        response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(dest);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look [here](https://docs.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm#CSharp) for a sample on how to talk to Oracle Bare Metal Cloud Services REST API from C#. This sample can be modified pretty easily to talk to the Object Storage service instead.